# Chrome extension refused to create a worker from blob because it violates the following Content Security Policy

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, sentry, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to implementing the [sentry.io][1] feature for debugging in my react chrome extension
But I'm unable to achieve my goal because of content security policy
I search about this problem but they are suggesting me to do add meta tag in index.html but I'm not using any html file

Here I'm directly injecting the react build into chrome tabs

The list of errors I'm getting while running: [![Errors][2]][2]

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "chrome extension",
  "description": "Request & record videos easily for interviews & testimonials",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "49",
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://*/*"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "downloads",
    "scripting",
    "activeTab",
    "tabCapture",
    "desktopCapture"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "sources/popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service_worker.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": [
        "content.js",
        "bundle.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": false
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "styles.css",
        "sources/*",
        "*"
      ],
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "use_dynamic_url": true
    }
  ],
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
      "*://localhost/*",
      "http://127.0.0.1:*/*",
      "*://*/*"
    ]
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' worker-src: '*' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self';"
  }
}
```

I've applied the csp in manifest file but I think i'm doing wrong

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/react";

Sentry.init({
    dsn: "https://5a063d0a833f3e0e1d6bf21eb8cd6bf5@o4506496546177024.ingest.us.sentry.io/4506890503782400",
    integrations: [
      Sentry.browserTracingIntegration(),
      Sentry.replayIntegration({
        maskAllText: false,
        blockAllMedia: false,
      }),
    ],
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
    tracePropagationTargets: ["localhost", /^https:\/\/yourserver\.io\/api/],
    replaysSessionSampleRate: 0.1,
    replaysOnErrorSampleRate: 1.0,
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('screen-recorder-mv3'))

reportWebVitals();
```

How I can get rid of these issues ? Thanks In Advance
[1]: https://sentry.io/
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCArG.png

Comment: MV3 extensions can't use eval or any constructed code like a blob-based worker in their pages directly. It can be done only inside a [sandboxed page/frame](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/sandbox/), but in your case it probably doesn't make any sense as you want to debug the main context. Try disabling workers in sentry or use a different package altogether.